# how can i add and remove elements of a listView?

Tags: android, database, listview, addition, erase

Hi guys im making my first android app, it has 4 fragments, inside one of those fragmentes a listView is gonna be displayed, and i need to give the option of adding and removing every element of the listView to the user (every element of the list view is supposed to link to a unique fragment that has some information regarding to it) , so where should i save the elements of the listView?

thanks very much.

im using java (android studio)

Comment: Please edit your post to address these issues:  What language are you using?  What's a fragment?  What code have you tried so far?

Comment: `ListView`s work in conjunction with an `Adapter` of sorts usually an implementation of `BaseAdapter` which bridges the data collection to the list view. By modifing the undelying collection and calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` you should be able to add/remove items.  If you provide your code we can help point out how/where this would be done.

Comment: @dg99 a Fragment is a standard Android UI component. We can presume the language is Java, though it should be tagged. But above all, OP, please share the code and/or ideas you have tried so far!